Connecting Azure Dedicated SQL Pool to Azure App Service (.NET Core)
We have a Azure Dedicated SQL Pool. We want to connect to it from our Azure App Service (.NET Core 8 C#) utilizing ADO.NET (SqlConnection and SqlCommand).
What the steps needed to enable this? Do we need to add the managed identity for the app service into the SQL Pool?

To my understanding, the appropriate tag is Azure Synapse. I add it and removed the tag for Azure SQL.

https://medium.com/@hilalyazbek/deploy-a-net-core-api-to-azure-app-service-and-azure-sql-91800eb540ef
Can you check if this helps

I tried accessing Azure Synapse Dedicated pool via my Asp.net, .Net 6.0 Web app and it ran successfully:-
In Services Folder > ProductService.cs:-
using sqlapp.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sqlapp.Services
{

    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public ProductService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        private SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {

            return new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection"));
        }
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            List<Product> _product_lst = new List<Product>();
            string _statement = "SELECT ProductID,ProductName,Quantity from Products";
            SqlConnection _connection = GetConnection();

            _connection.Open();

            SqlCommand _sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(_statement, _connection);

            using (SqlDataReader _reader = _sqlcommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (_reader.Read())
                {
                    Product _product = new Product()
                    {
                        ProductID = _reader.GetInt32(0),
                        ProductName = _reader.GetString(1),
                        Quantity = _reader.GetInt32(2)
                    };

                    _product_lst.Add(_product);
                }
            }
            _connection.Close();
            return _product_lst;
        }

    }
}

In Pages Folder > Index.cshtml:-
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">This is a list of Products</h1>    
    <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    
        @foreach(var product in Model.Products)
                {
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@product.ProductID</th>
                    <td>@product.ProductName</td>
                    <td>@product.Quantity</td>
                    </tr>
                }                
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

Azure synapse Dedicated pool ado.net connection string, Reference:-
Name: SQLConnection
Value: Server=tcp:xxxorkspace45.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Initial Catalog=pooldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxser;Password=Wxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;


Add the below setting in the connection string of the Web app:-

Azure Synapse Networking setting, allowing access from all Azure services:-

Output:-

